# Get parent class name in Resharper LiveTemplate

Tags: c#, resharper, live-templates

I want to add a live template that creates a nested CommandImplementation class.
The template itself looks like this:

```
   public ICommand $COMMAND$
    {
        get { return new $COMMAND$Impl(self: this); }
    }

    private class $COMMAND$Impl : ICommand
    {
        private readonly $PARENT_CLASS$ self;

        public $COMMAND$Impl($PARENT_CLASS$ self)
        {
            this.self = self;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {

        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

The macro for `$PARENT_CLASS$` is "Containing type name", which evaluates to `$COMMAND$Impl` and not the class containing all this stuff.

What can I do to get the name of the class this template is inserted into?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a macro that gives the outermost containing type. Ideally, the containing type macro would provide a completion list of all containing types, allowing you to select the appropriate value - I've added a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-442855) for this that you can track and vote on.

This can also be achieved with a custom plugin, but [implementing your own macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Features/LiveTemplates/Macros.html).